# Google sheets macro to run on worksheet change

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-macro

I have a simple macro in Google Sheets that I can run from Tools > Macros > MacroName.  I have it set up with a trigger to run when the spreadsheet is first opened.  (All the macro does is go to the first empty cell in column A, from https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/101200)

However, what I would really like to do is to have this macro run every/any time the active sheet is changed in my spreadsheet.  So when I click on a sheet's tab at the bottom of the screen to open a different sheet (in the same google sheets spreadsheet file), the macro runs.  If I change back to the previous worksheet tab the macro runs, etc.

In Excel there's a function Worksheet.Activate which I believe would do what I want there, but I can't find a matching function in Google Sheets.

How can I get a macro to run when the active sheet changes?  (Only within the one spreadsheet)

Answer (score 1):

See Tanaike's gist "[Change Tab Detection on Google Spreadsheet using onSelectionChange Event Trigger with Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/524c16dbef722763f80312357d0e4368)".

You may also want to take a look at the [jumpToToday_](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/32097728?msgid=33126935) script which would probably be an easier way to quickly go to the spots of recent interest in each sheet of your spreadsheet.